# Need help analyzing torque transfer and slippage condition between parts

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical, mechanical-failure

I have a scenario where Plate A (light blue) shown in the image below is being pressed against two different plates that are in contact with different sections of Plate A. I would like to know which of the two surfaces, if any could see slippage occur when a Moment is applied to Plate A such that it attempts to rotate on the surfaces below under the Axial Force it is subjected to.

All dimensions below are in mm.

[image: Scenario Diagram]

[image: Zoomed Cross-section]

Some assumptions we will make about all the plates include that they are infinitely stiff and we will not consider anything going on internally in the parts i.e. it is transferring all the axial load perfectly through it into the surfaces underneath in the case of Plate A.

Defining a few parameters:

- Material of Plate A: Steel
- Material of Plate B: Aluminum
- Material of Plate C: Steel

Coefficients of friction between surfaces *(surfaces in this example are lubricated/greased)*:

- Steel-Steel, μ = 0.15
- Aluminum-Steel, μ = 0.1

Axial force applied to the top surface of Plate A is F<sub>A</sub> = 32.9kN and a Moment M<sub>z</sub> = 20Nm. The surface area of Plate A is A<sub>1</sub> = 340mm<sup>2</sup>. The surface areas of the underside of Plate A are A<sub>2</sub> = 90mm<sup>2</sup> and A<sub>3</sub> = 200mm<sup>2</sup>.

I would like to know that given the axial load on Plate A, will there be any slippage on either of the plates underneath when the moment is applied to Plate A. If it does slip, what would be the new required F<sub>A</sub> to prevent slippage.

**UPDATE: Let us assume also the Force is split evenly across the two surfaces on the underside of Plate A. I have updated the geometry to better reflect this scenario.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like homework.

Comment: This question is actually related to bearing design for my own project, not related to any homework. The image above is for a presser flange required by a cross roller bearing and the values I am running are what I calculated to be required bolt preload values. Too bad there is no consistent answer in all of the comments so far that converge on an answer from a first principles perspective.

Comment: Also when the forum instructions ask to make the question well written and clear, the first time I post I get accused of making it look like a homework question? It looks like a question out of a textbook because I spent the time to make it clear for the people reading...Ill make sure next time its a hot mess

Comment: Often people post with some solutions suggested or partially worked through correct or not...

Comment: What do you mean by the assumption that the force is split evenly? Like half the force on each of the contact areas or just uniform pressure?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions make it impossible to analyse accurately, because the axial load will be split between B and C depending on the stiffness of the system, which will be hard to calculate by hand. However, there are two cases we can look at, all the torque goes through B, or all through C. It is trivially obvious that the latter would slip first, so for B 16mm*.15*32.9 kN= 79 Nm, which is more than your applied torque, so it won't slip. Areas are unimportant in 'high school' friction problems. In the real world of course they are very important. If this is being used as a clutch I'd get rid of the unneeded contact between A and C, it might cause galling.

Comment: Just wondering if you could look at the updated section with the assumption that the axial load will be split evenly. I have updated the geometry to better reflect this scenario occuring. I am curious on your opinion on the answer below utilizing surface area and relating it back to Maximum Torque seen at those surfaces.

Comment: Since I know surface area is not important I'm not going to reverse engineer the other answers. So if B and C share the axial load then B is 40 Nm and C is tiny, 7mm*0.1*32.9/2 kN= 11.5 Nm, so the total is about 51 Nm. Even C by itself would be just adequate.

Comment: Sorry just trying to pick your brain here Greg, how are you going about selecting the value of the radius to plug into your equation here, are we just picking the mid point of each cylindrical surface of Plate A i.e. 7mm for the surface contacting B defined by the inner R of 6mm and the upper R of 8mm.

To build onto that, why would you disregard the total range of values that exist along that surface to use for calculating the maximum allowable moment before slippage. 

Sorry for all the questions!

Comment: The contact is so narrow radially there's no point in finessing the calculation, so I just took the mid point.

Answer (score 0):

From the $\infty$ stiffness assumption, the axial force will lead to uniform contact pressure between the plates (this will not be true in reality and might affect the results significantly).
$$P = \frac{F_A}{A} = \frac{32900}{\pi\cdot\frac{16^2-12^2}{4}+\pi\cdot\frac{34^2-30^2}{4}} \approx 113.83 MPa$$
(The contact areas are calculated based on drawing dimensions and assuming all parts are axisymmmetric, the areas you provided did not make sense to me.)
Uniform pressure $P$ acting on area $dA$ in distance $r$ from the axis can create maximum torque $dT_{max}$ through friction:
$$dT_{max} = P\cdot dA\cdot \mu\cdot r$$
You can get the full torque by integrating this on across the full contact area:
$$T_{max} = \mu\cdot P\cdot \int\limits_A r\cdot dA = \mu\cdot P\cdot I_p$$
$\mu$ and $P$ will be constants and the integral of area times distance from center is polar moment of inertia $I_p$.

The [polar moment of inertia for circular ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_polar_moment_of_area#Hollow_Cylinder) is:
$$I_p = \pi\cdot\frac{D^4-d^4}{32}$$
So in your case:
$$I_{p2} = \pi\cdot\frac{16^4-12^4}{32} \approx 4398.23 mm^4$$
$$I_{p3} = \pi\cdot\frac{34^4-30^4}{32} \approx 51672.9 mm^4$$
Maximum torque in steel-aluminum contact:
$$T_{max2} = \mu_{a-s}\cdot P\cdot I_{p2} \approx 50.065 N\cdot m$$
Maximum torque in steel-steel contact:
$$T_{max3} = \mu_{s-s}\cdot P\cdot I_{p3} \approx 882.292 N\cdot m$$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply Tomas, I noticed you mentioned the provided areas did not make sense, they are just from the CAD program and I rounded them a little for the example. 

What I wanted to ask is why you took the approach of calculating pressure here, another comment provided in this post mentioned that surface area and thus pressure was no important to consider. What are you thoughts on this?

Comment: Another question would be why the units of Maximum Torque not align to the variables in the equation. You have P in MPa (N/mm^2) multiplied by polar second moment of area that has units of mm^4. The coefficient has no units, therefore this equation is missing either a variable or is incorrect because the final unit would be N*mm^2 before you divided out the answer by 1000. So for Tmax2 is not 50065.05209 N/mm^2?

Comment: @SoloLeveling pressure is a factor in every clutch system I have worked on, lack of sufficient pressure guarantees slipping and damage.

Comment: @SolarMike I just want to clarify my question is not a clutch system, but simply looking for a way to understand when slipping occurs. My understanding is that the surface area is a not a factor to look at when we are talking about friction in a system (therefore pressure is not), fundamentally its not part of the equation. But to overcome friction there must be another greater force applied in the opposing direction. In the above question I am curious how I can get get that vector given that the normal force is divided and the geometry is not a simple cube on a plane as in "homwork".

Comment: In many cases with friction, the surface pressure is really not important. However in this case, what produces the torque is not just overall friction force, but its product with the lever arm. This in case of uniform pressure leads to the expression using $I_p$, however in real case, the pressure distribution would probably not be uniform, so you would have to integrate the second formula in general with $P(r,\varphi)$ to calculate the maximum torque sustained by friction.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume the plates as rigid then we can assume the pressure evenly distributed between plates.

- pressure on lower still and aluminum plate= $ \frac{32.9kN}{90+200}=11.34N/mm^2 $
- Friction force on lower steel plate = $90*0.15* 11.34 = 154.3N$
- Approximate radius of lower steel plate Rs = 6+8/2 = 7mm
- Resistive torque of steel plate $ T_s= Fs*Rs=154.3*7 = 1080.1Nmm$
- Friction force on alum plate= $F_a = 200*0.01* 11.34 = 22.68N $
- approximate $R_a = 16mm$
- Resistive torque of aluminum plate $ T_a = F_a * R_a = 22.68*16 = 362Nmm$
  So the total resistive torque is $T_t = 1080.1+362=1442.1Nmm >> 20Nmm$

So no slippage under the torque you have.

However the alum plate will start to skid first if we increase the torque a lot.